# Is there a way we can customize email for each Docusign notification event?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send notification emails to recipients via Docusign API. I was able to send custom email to each recipients using `EmailSubject` and `EmailBody` in `RecipientEmailNotification()` for each `Signer`. When the envelope is sent, the recipients received the customized email subjects and bodies which is correct:

[image]

However, when all parties signed the envelope. The signers get a notification email which has the subject: "Completed [Email Subject]". The email body text that was supposed to be displayed only when the envelope is sent was also added to this completed email notification:

[image: Notification email when envelope is completed]

I want to customize the subject and body of the notification emails that are sent to all signers when the envelope is completed (signed by all parties). Is there a way we can do this using the DocuSign API?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for you (untested)

1. See if changing the email branding file can help.
2. [Stop the envelope processing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/pause-unpause-workflow/) after the last signer. Then update the email subject and blurb, then restart the processing.

Note that you can test the second idea from the web app:

1. Create an envelope with two signers (use your own emails). Set the subject and email content body. Send the envelope.
2. As the first signer, sign the envelope.
3. Login as the `sender`. Modify (correct) the envelope with the new email subject and body that you want people to receive at the end of the process.
4. The first signer was the only "real" signer. The second signer was merely to insert a pause into the envelope processing. Now, as the second signer, sign the envelope (ignore the email's subject/body).
5. The envelope is now complete. The first signer (and sender) should now receive the "envelope is complete" email. Check to see that it uses your updated email subject/body. If so, then automate the above via the API. (Use pause/unpause instead of an extra signer.)